# Querying for X when attr == A and Y when attr == B in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is the query I'm trying to run. [Screenshot.](http://awesomescreenshot.com/01c2h5w357)

```
@colleges = College.all
@colleges = @colleges.where(category: @university_type) unless @university_type.blank? or @university_type.all? &:blank?
@colleges = @colleges.where("us_news_ranking <= ?", @rank_low) unless @rank_low.blank?
@colleges = @colleges.where("(sat_math_25+sat_math_75+sat_reading_25+sat_reading_75)/2 >= ?", @sat_low) unless @sat_low.blank?
@colleges = @colleges.where("(sat_math_25+sat_math_75+sat_reading_25+sat_reading_75)/2 <= ?", @sat_high) unless @sat_high.blank?    
@colleges = @colleges.where("(act_composite_25+act_composite_75)/2 >= ?", @act_low) unless @act_low.blank?
@colleges = @colleges.where("(act_composite_25+act_composite_75)/2 <= ?", @act_high) unless @act_high.blank?
if !@cost_low.blank?
    if @in_state.blank?
        @colleges = @colleges.where("out_of_state_tuition+room_and_board >= ?", @cost_low)
        @colleges = @colleges.where("out_of_state_tuition+room_and_board <= ?", @cost_high)
    else
        @colleges = @colleges.where(state: @in_state).where("in_state_tuition+room_and_board >= ? AND in_state_tuition+room_and_board <= ?", @cost_low, @cost_high)
        @colleges = @colleges.where("state != ? AND out_of_state_tuition+room_and_board >= ? AND out_of_state_tuition+room_and_board <= ?", @in_state, @cost_low, @cost_high)
    end
end
```

I've tested it, and the problem is with the else statement. If I comment out one of the lines in the else statement, the other one behaves as you'd expect. However, when I leave them both uncommented, it never returns any colleges.

I don't know what the problem is, but I figure that it has something to do with me querying for `state = A` in one line, and `state = B` in the other. Is that the problem? Why? If not, what is the problem?

**College.rb**

```
  def self.get_college(university_type, rank_low, sat_low, sat_high, act_low, act_high, in_state, cost_low, cost_high)
    colleges = College.all
    colleges = colleges.where(category: university_type) unless university_type.blank? or university_type.all? &:blank?
    colleges = colleges.where("us_news_ranking <= ?", rank_low) unless rank_low.blank?
    colleges = colleges.where("(sat_math_25+sat_math_75+sat_reading_25+sat_reading_75)/2 >= ?", sat_low) unless sat_low.blank?
    colleges = colleges.where("(sat_math_25+sat_math_75+sat_reading_25+sat_reading_75)/2 <= ?", sat_high) unless sat_high.blank?    
    colleges = colleges.where("(act_composite_25+act_composite_75)/2 >= ?", act_low) unless act_low.blank?
    colleges = colleges.where("(act_composite_25+act_composite_75)/2 <= ?", act_high) unless act_high.blank?
    select_fields = sanitize_sql_array( [ <<-ENDSQL, in_state ] )
                      *,
                      IF( colleges.state = ?,
                          in_state_tuition,
                          out_of_state_tuition
                      ) AS user_tuition,
                      user_tuition + room_and_board AS total_cost
                    ENDSQL

    colleges = colleges.select(select_fields).where("total_cost BETWEEN ? AND ?", cost_low, cost_high)    

    return colleges
  end
```

**tools_controller.rb**

```
@colleges = College.get_college(@university_type, @rank_low, @sat_low, @sat_high, @act_low, @act_high, @in_state, @cost_low, @cost_high) if @searched
```

Comment: What is `@colleges` set to before the `if`? What SQL does this generate?

Comment: @Jordan I updated my question to show. I also added a screnshot.

Comment: What SQL does it generate?

Comment: I don't know what SQL it generates. See [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions) for some ideas though.

Comment: That's the first thing you need to check, then. In development mode every SQL statement is logged. Look at your log (in the console where you started `rails server`).

Comment: @Jordan Oh ok. Here's the sql: `SELECT "colleges".* FROM "colleges" WHERE "colleges"."state" = 'New York' AND (in_state_tuition+room_and_board >= 0 AND in_state_tuition+room_and_board <= 30000) AND (state != 'New York' AND out_of_state_tuition+room_and_board >= 0 AND out_of_state_tuition+room_and_board <= 30000)`

Answer (score 1):

### Update following @AdamZerner's comment:

> Say the user selects a price range and a state. I want to return colleges in the price range, and to do that I see if `tuition` + `room_and_board` are in that range. But I want to calculate tuition using `in_state_tuition` if the user is in-state, and `out_of_state_tuition` if the user is out-of-state.

Ah, good question. As I mentioned, you need to know SQL, not just Rails. A nice, clean query for getting what you want looks like this:

```sql
SELECT *,
       IF( colleges.state = @user_state,
           in_state_tuition,
           out_of_state_tuition
       ) AS user_tuition,
       user_tuition + room_and_board AS total_cost
  FROM colleges
 WHERE total_cost BETWEEN @cost_low AND @cost_high
```

We use an `IF()` expression to decide whether to use `in_state_tuition` or `out_of_state_tuition` and give it a name, `user_tuition`. Then we take that and add it to `room_and_board` to get `total_cost`. Then in our `WHERE` we use `BETWEEN`, because it's much more concise and readable than `A <= B AND B <= C`.

Once we know what our SQL looks like, it's easy to translate into ActiveRecord methods.

```
# This will give you the `SELECT` part of the query above
select_fields = sanitize_sql_array( [ <<-ENDSQL, @in_state ] )
                  *,
                  IF( colleges.state = ?,
                      in_state_tuition,
                      out_of_state_tuition
                  ) AS user_tuition,
                  user_tuition + room_and_board AS total_cost
                ENDSQL

@colleges = College.select(select_fields)
                   .where("total_cost BETWEEN ? AND ?", @cost_low, @cost_high)
```

Note that `sanitize_sql_array` is a [protected method of ActiveRecord::Base](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods/sanitize_sql_array), so it will only work inside your model. But querying logic like this belongs in the model anyway. Your use case is perfect for Rails scopes:

```
class College < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :ranked_at_least, ->(rank=nil) {
    return self if rank.nil?
    where("us_news_ranking <= ?", rank)
  }

  scope :in_state_with_cost_between, ->(state_name, cost_low, cost_high) {
    select_fields = sanitize_sql_array( [ <<-ENDSQL, state_name ] )
                      *,
                      IF( colleges.state = ?,
                          in_state_tuition,
                          out_of_state_tuition
                      ) AS user_tuition,
                      user_tuition + room_and_board AS total_cost
                    ENDSQL

    select(select_fields)
      .where("total_cost BETWEEN ? AND ?", cost_low, cost_high)
  }

  scope :with_sat_composite_between, ->(score_low, score_high) {
    # ...
  }
  # ...and so on...
end
```

This would allow you to make nice, clean queries like this:

```
College.in_state_with_cost_between("New York", 10_000, 50_000).
  ranked_at_least(20).
  with_sat_composite_between(1_200, 1_500)
```

...which seems a lot nicer to me.

---

### Update 2 - Simpler and works with SQLite

I didn't realize that SQLite doesn't have `IF()`. I think the `sanitize_sql_array` bit overcomplicated things a bit, too, so let's simplify. The below SQLite query is equivalent to the one above (which works in MySQL and others):

```sql
SELECT colleges.*,
       CASE WHEN colleges.state = 'New York'
         THEN colleges.in_state_tuition
         ELSE colleges.out_of_state_tuition 
       END AS user_tuition,
       user_tuition + room_and_board AS total_cost
  FROM colleges
 WHERE total_cost BETWEEN 15000 AND 60000
```

The only difference is that we used `CASE WHEN x THEN y ELSE z END` instead of `IF(x, y, z)`.

Now let's turn it into an ActiveRecord query:

```ruby
# Always sanitize values you get from the user!
safe_state_name = ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize(@in_state)

select_sql = <<-ENDSQL
  colleges.*,
  CASE WHEN colleges.state = #{safe_state_name}
    THEN colleges.in_state_tuition
    ELSE colleges.out_of_state_tuition
  END AS user_tuition,
  user_tuition + room_and_board AS total_cost
ENDSQL

College.select(select_sql).
  where("total_cost BETWEEN ? AND ?", @cost_low, @cost_high)
```

When we use the "`?`" replacement in `where()` Rails automatically sanitizes `@cost_low` and `@cost_high` for us, but we have to do it manually for the `select()`. Don't skip this step, though--it's very important!

We could also have written the query this way:

```ruby
where_sql = <<-ENDSQL
  ( CASE WHEN colleges.state = ?
         THEN colleges.in_state_tuition
         ELSE colleges.out_of_state_tuition
    END
  ) BETWEEN ? AND ?
ENDSQL

College.where(where_sql, @in_state, @cost_low, @cost_high)
```

...but I think using `select()` makes for cleaner queries, and also let you use a calculated value (e.g. `user_tuition`, `total_cost`) multiple times.

Scopes are a core part of Rails and learning to use them will help you write maintainable code. If you don't know scopes, you don't know rails. They're also really easy. In this case we could write a scope like this:

```ruby
class College < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :for_state_with_cost_between, ->(state_name, cost_low, cost_high) {
    safe_state_name = ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize(state_name)

    select_sql = <<-ENDSQL
      colleges.*,
      CASE WHEN colleges.state = #{safe_state_name}
        THEN colleges.in_state_tuition
        ELSE colleges.out_of_state_tuition
      END AS user_tuition,
      user_tuition + room_and_board AS total_cost
    ENDSQL

    select(select_sql).
      where("total_cost BETWEEN ? AND ?", cost_low, cost_high)
  }
  # ...
```

This is basically equivalent to defining a class method like this:

```ruby
class College < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.for_state_with_cost_between(state_name, cost_low, cost_high)
    safe_state_name = ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize(state_name)

    select_sql = # ...

    self.select(select_sql).where("total_cost BETWEEN ? AND ?", cost_low, cost_high)
  end
  # ...
```

In both cases you would use it like this:

```ruby
College.for_state_with_cost_between("New York", 10_000, 50_000)
```

Using scopes your code could be written to be much cleaner and readable with less room for bugs. I didn't want to paste the whole thing here, but [take a look at this gist](https://gist.github.com/jrunning/9511047) (untested, of course).

---

### Original answer

Let's break it down. First you do this:

```
@colleges = College.all
# ...let's pretend you didn't do anything here...
@colleges = @colleges.where( state: @in_state )
                     .where( "in_state_tuition + room_and_board >= ? AND
                              in_state_tuition + room_and_board <= ?",
                             @cost_low, @cost_high )
```

This creates a ActiveRecord::Relation and assigns it to `@colleges`. If you called `@colleges.all` now, it would generate and execute SQL like this (more or less):

```sql
SELECT * FROM colleges
 WHERE state = @in_state AND
       in_state_tuition + room_and_board >= @cost_low AND
       in_state_tuition + room_and_board <= @cost_high
```

Next you do this:

```
@colleges = @colleges.where( "state != ? AND
                              out_of_state_tuition + room_and_board >= ? AND
                              out_of_state_tuition+room_and_board <= ?",
                              @in_state, @cost_low, @cost_high )
```

This takes the ActiveRecord::Relation object you created above and adds more WHERE conditions on to it. If you did `@colleges.all` now, it would generate and execute SQL like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM colleges
 WHERE ( state = @in_state AND
         in_state_tuition + room_and_board >= @cost_low AND
         in_state_tuition + room_and_board <= @cost_high
       ) AND
       ( state != @in_state AND
         out_of_state_tuition + room_and_board >= @cost_low AND
         out_of_state_tuition + room_and_board <= @cost_high
       )
```

This makes it pretty obvious what the problem is. You have `state = @in_state` and `state != @in_state` in the same query. A `state` can't be "New York" and *not* "New York" at the same time, so your result is empty.

ActiveRecord gives you some nice abstractions and convenience methods for doing database queries, but in the end it's still very important to know what kind of SQL it's generating and what it means.

Comment: Ok. So how would I write the query?

Comment: What result are you trying to get? It's not clear from your question.

Comment: See this [screenshot](http://awesomescreenshot.com/01c2h5w357). Say the user selects a price range and a state. I want to return colleges in the price range, and to do that I see if tuition+room_and_board are in that range. But I want to calculate tuition using `in_state_tuition` if the user is in-state, and `out_of_state_tuition` if the user is out-of-state.

Comment: I don't understand scopes, so I'd prefer not to use them. I tried `colleges = colleges.find_by_sql("SELECT *, IF( colleges.state = in_state, in_state_tuition, out_of_state_tuition) AS user_tuition, user_tuition + room_and_board AS total_cost FROM colleges WHERE total_cost BETWEEN cost_low AND cost_high")`, and that didn't work. It gives me this error `SQLite3::SQLException: no such function: IF `.

Comment: I also tried `select_fields = sanitize_sql_array( [ <<-ENDSQL, in_state ] ) *, IF( colleges.state = ?, in_state_tuition, out_of_state_tuition) AS user_tuition, user_tuition + room_and_board AS total_cost ENDSQL

colleges = colleges.select(select_fields).where("total_cost BETWEEN ? AND ?", cost_low, cost_high)` in my Model, but it also didn't work. This was the error: `SQLite3::SQLException: no such function: IF`. Note: I used parameters instead of instance variables because I'm in the Model.

Comment: I updated my question with code so it's easier to read than the comments.

Comment: @AdamZerner Sorry about that, please take a look at my updated answer ("Update 2"), and the link at the end of that section.

Comment: `safe_state_name = ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize(in_state)
 select_sql = <<-ENDSQL
   colleges.*,
   CASE WHEN colleges.state = #{safe_state_name}
  THEN colleges.in_state_tuition
  ELSE colleges.out_of_state_tuition
   END AS user_tuition,
   user_tuition + room_and_board AS total_cost
 ENDSQL
 colleges.select(select_sql).where("total_cost BETWEEN ? AND ?", cost_low, cost_high)` didn't work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49589/discussion-between-adam-zerner-and-jordan)